# Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getTable()" because "classMapping" is null

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase

I have an entity "MasterSegment" with a composite key as the primary key. This key has a reference to another entity "BkrApplication". When I start the app without Liquibase, tables are generated perfectly and everything works fine.

```
public class MasterSegment extends Auditable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MasterSegmentId id;
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId("appId")
    private BkrApplication app;
    // getters setters omitted
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class MasterSegmentId implements Serializable {
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "app_id", nullable = false)
    private Long appId;
    // getters setters omitted
}
```

The problem is when I try to generate a Liquibase migration using `mvn clean install liquibase:diff`, I get the following error: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getTable()" because "classMapping" is null.

Without any hint in the exception message, and after many hours of debugging, I noticed that @MapsId causes the issue. I try to remove it and I got mapping issues.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks